# Find the shortest substring whose replacement makes the string contain equal number of each character

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, algorithm, optimization

I have a string of length `n` composed of letters `A`,`G`,`C` and `T`. The string is steady if it contains equal number of `A`,`G`,`C` and `T`(each `n/4` times). I need to find the minimum length of the substring that when replaced makes it steady. Here's a [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bear-and-steady-gene) to the full description of the problem.

Suppose `s1=AAGAAGAA`.

Now since `n=8` ideally it should have 2 `A`s, 2 `T`s, 2 `G`s and 2 `C`s. It has 4 excessive `A`s. Hence we need a substring which contains at least 4 `A`s.

I start by taking a 4 character substring from left and if not found then I increment a variable `mnum`(ie look for 5 variable substrings and so on).

We get `AAGAA` as an answer. **But it's too slow.**

```
 from collections import Counter
 import sys
 n=int(input())       #length of string
 s1=input()
 s=Counter(s1)
 le=int(n/4)          #ideal length of each element
 comp={'A':le,'G':le,'C':le,'T':le}    #dictionary containing equal number of all elements
 s.subtract(comp)     #Finding by how much each element ('A','G'...) is in excess or loss
 a=[]
 b=[]
 for x in s.values():   #storing frequency(s.values--[4,2]) of elements which are in excess
    if(x>0):
      a.append(x)
 for x in s.keys():         #storing corresponding elements(s.keys--['A','G'])
    if(s[x]>0):
       b.append(x)
 mnum=sum(a)            #minimum substring length to start with
 if(mnum==0):
   print(0)
   sys.exit
 flag=0
 while(mnum<=n):  #(when length 4 substring with all the A's and G's is not found increasing to 5 and so on)
    for i in range(n-mnum+1):     #Finding substrings with length mnum in s1
       for j in range(len(a)):    #Checking if all of excess elements are present
           if(s1[i:i+mnum].count(b[j])==a[j]):
              flag=1
           else:
              flag=0

       if(flag==1):
          print(mnum)
          sys.exit()
    mnum+=1
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's one solution with limited testing done. This should give you some ideas on how to improve your code.

```
from collections import Counter
import sys
import math

n = int(input())
s1 = input()
s = Counter(s1)

if all(e <= n/4 for e in s.values()):
    print(0)
    sys.exit(0)

result = math.inf
out = 0
for mnum in range(n):
    s[s1[mnum]] -= 1
    while all(e <= n/4 for e in s.values()) and out <= mnum:
        result = min(result, mnum - out + 1)
        s[s1[out]] += 1
        out += 1

print(result)
```

Answer (score 5):

The minimal substring can be found in `O(N)` time and `O(N)` space.

First count a frequency `fr[i]` of each character from the input of length `n`.
Now, the most important thing to realise is that the necessary and sufficient condition for a substring to be considered minimal, it must contain each excessive character with a frequency of at least `fr[i] - n/4`. Otherwise, it won't be possible to replace the missing characters. So, our task is to go through each such substring and pick the one with the minimal length.

But how to find all of them efficiently?

At start, `minLength` is `n`. We introduce `2` pointer indices - `left` and `right` (initially `0`) that define a substring from `left` to `right` in the original string `str`. Then, we increment `right` until the frequency of each excessive character in `str[left:right]` is at least `fr[i] - n/4`. But it's not all yet since `str[left : right]` may contain unnecessary chars to the left (for example, they're not excessive and so can be removed). So, we increment `left` as long as `str[left : right]` still contains enough excessive elements. When we're finished we update `minLength` if it's larger than `right - left`. We repeat the procedure until `right >= n`.

Let's consider an example. Let `GAAAAAAA` be the input string. Then, the algorithm steps are as below:

1.Count frequencies of each character:

```
['G'] = 1, ['A'] = 6, ['T'] = 0, ['C'] = 0 ('A' is excessive here)
```

2.Now iterate through the original string:

```
Step#1: |G|AAAAAAA
    substr = 'G' - no excessive chars (left = 0, right = 0) 
Step#2: |GA|AAAAAA
    substr = 'GA' - 1 excessive char, we need 5 (left = 0, right = 1)
Step#3: |GAA|AAAAA
    substr = 'GAA' - 2 excessive chars, we need 5 (left = 0, right = 2)
Step#4: |GAAA|AAAA
    substr = 'GAAA' - 3 excessive chars, we need 5 (left = 0, right = 3)
Step#5: |GAAAA|AAA
    substr = 'GAAAA' - 4 excessive chars, we need 5 (left = 0, right = 4)
Step#6: |GAAAAA|AA
    substr = 'GAAAAA' - 5 excessive chars, nice but can we remove something from left? 'G' is not excessive anyways. (left = 0, right = 5)
Step#7: G|AAAAA|AA
    substr = 'AAAAA' - 5 excessive chars, wow, it's smaller now. minLength = 5 (left = 1, right = 5)   
Step#8: G|AAAAAA|A
    substr = 'AAAAAA' - 6 excessive chars, nice, but can we reduce the substr? There's a redundant 'A'(left = 1, right = 6)
Step#9: GA|AAAAA|A
    substr = 'AAAAA' - 5 excessive chars, nice, minLen = 5 (left = 2, right = 6)
Step#10: GA|AAAAAA|
    substr = 'AAAAAA' - 6 excessive chars, nice, but can we reduce the substr? There's a redundant 'A'(left = 2, right = 7)
Step#11: GAA|AAAAA|
    substr = 'AAAAA' - 5 excessive chars, nice, minLen = 5 (left = 3, right = 7)
Step#12: That's it as right >= 8
```

Or the full code below:

```
from collections import Counter

n = int(input())
gene = raw_input()
char_counts = Counter()
for i in range(n):
    char_counts[gene[i]] += 1

n_by_4 = n / 4
min_length = n
left = 0
right = 0

substring_counts = Counter()
while right < n:
    substring_counts[gene[right]] += 1
    right += 1

    has_enough_excessive_chars = True
    for ch in "ACTG":
        diff = char_counts[ch] - n_by_4
        # the char cannot be used to replace other items
        if (diff > 0) and (substring_counts[ch] < diff):
            has_enough_excessive_chars = False
            break

    if has_enough_excessive_chars:
        while left < right and substring_counts[gene[left]] > (char_counts[gene[left]] - n_by_4):
            substring_counts[gene[left]] -= 1
            left += 1

        min_length = min(min_length, right - left)

print (min_length)
```

Comment: Nice logic, but can you help me elaborate on how this came to your mind? Or this algorthm is rather familiar, but I cannot think up of another example of it, can you point out the origin of the algorithm?

Comment: @cxz maybe there's an existing algorithm, but I'm not aware of it. How did I come to this? Each substring candidate must have enough redundant characters to be replaced with. So, we don't have to check all the possible substrings, but only those having enough redundant characters, and this is achievable in `O(n)`