# Smallest substring that can be replaced to make the string have the same number of each character

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve a problem that is almost exactly that. In particular I'm given a string `s` such that `s.Length % 4 == 0` and each `s[i]` is one of `'A'`, `'C'`, `'T'` or `'G'`. I want to find the smallest substring that I can replace so that each of `'A'`, `'C'`, `'T'` and `'G'` appears exactly `s.Length / 4` times.

For example, with `s="GAAATAAA"`, one optimal solution is to replace a substring `"AAATA"` with `"TTCCG"`, resulting in `"GTTCCGAA"`.

I've decribed my approach in the comments below and I'm wondering whether it's genereally correct in that it will get me to the correct answer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
class Solution
{
    static string ReplacementForSteadiness(string s)
    {   
        var counter = new Dictionary<char,int>() {
            { 'A', 0 }, { 'C', 0 }, { 'G', 0 }, { 'T', 0 }
        };
        for(int i = 0; i < s.Length; ++i)
                counter[s[i]] += 1;

        int div = s.Length / 4;

        var pairs = counter.ToList();
        if(pairs.All(p => p.Value == div))
            return "";

        // If here, that means there is an even count of characters in s. For example, if
        // s = "AAATGTTCTTGCGGGG", then counter = { A -> 3, T -> 5, C -> 2, G -> 6 },
        // div = 4, and we know that we need to increase the number of As by 1, decrease 
        // the number of Ts by 1, increase the number of Cs by 2 and decrease the number
        // of Gs by 2.

        // The smallest strings to replace will have 1 T and 2 Gs, to be replaced with 1 A and
        // 2 Cs (The order of characters in the replacement string doesn't matter).
        // "TGG" --> "ACC" 
        // "GTG" --> "ACC"
        // "GGT" --> "ACC"

        // None of those strings exist in s. The next smallest strings that could be replaced
        // would have 1 T and 3Gs, to be replaced with 1 A and 2 of the Gs to be replaced with
        // Cs. Or, 2 Ts and 2Gs, 1 of the Ts to be replaced by an A and both the Gs to be replaced
        // by Cs.
        // "TGGG" --> "AGCC"
        // "GTGG" --> "AGCC"
        // "GGTG" --> "AGCC"
        // "GGGT" --> "AGCC"
        // "TTGG" --> "ATCC"
        // "TGTG" --> "ATCC"
        // "GTGT" --> "ATCC"
        // "GGTT" --> "ATCC"

        // None of those strings exist in s. Etc.      

        string r;

        // ... 

        return r;
    }

    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
       Console.ReadLine(); // n
       string str = Console.ReadLine();
       string replacement = ReplacementForSteadiness(str);
       Console.WriteLine(replacement.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bear and Steady gene - improve solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579917/bear-and-steady-gene-improve-solution)

Answer (score 0):

If the string already has a balanced set of characters then you are done and do not have to do anything.

Otherwise you can always solve the problem by replacing zero characters which is the minimum. You do this by adding whatever characters are missing. So for example to take your test case:

GAAATAAA

The character with most occurrences is A with 6. You need 5 additional G's, 5 additional T's and 6 additional C's. So, replace one A with the needed characters including the A itself:

GAAATAA[AGGGGGTTTTTCCCCCC]

Since the original A is replaced with an A, you have actually replaced zero characters, the minimum possible.

Comment: Although the OP doesn't explicitly say so, I believe (based on the example, and the fact that, as you show, the problem can otherwise be solved very easily) that the replacement string must be the same length as the replaced string.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution will work but its complexity is too hight. 
Here is an alternative solution 
If counting characters in your string returns { 'A', 4 }, { 'C', 6 }, { 'G', 6 }, { 'T', 4 } the substring that has to start with C or G, end with C or G and have a length >= 2 
So what we need to do is take each string that verify those condition, test if it contains 'the bad characters' in our case one C and one G. If its length = 2 we win otherwise we save in a temporary variable and continue our test

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
class Solution
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        string[] inputs = { "GAAATAAA", "CACCGCTACCGC", "CAGCTAGC", "AAAAAAAA", "GAAAAAAA", "GATGAATAACCA", "ACGT" };

        List<string> replacement = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in inputs)
        {
            replacement.Add(StringThatHasToBeReplaced(item));
        }
    }

    static string StringThatHasToBeReplaced(string s)
    {
        var counter = new Dictionary<char, int>() {
            { 'A', 0 }, { 'C', 0 }, { 'G', 0 }, { 'T', 0 }
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; ++i)
            counter[s[i]] += 1;

        int div = s.Length / 4;
        var pairs = counter.ToList();

        if (pairs.Where(p => p.Value != div).Count() == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        List<char> surplusCharacter = pairs.Where(p => p.Value > div).Select(p => p.Key).ToList();
        int minLength = pairs.Where(p => p.Value > div).Sum(p => p.Value - div);
        string result = s;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length - minLength + 1; i++) // i is the start index
        {
            if (surplusCharacter.Contains(s[i]))
            {
                if (minLength == 1)
                    return s[i].ToString();

                for (int j = i + minLength - 1; j < s.Length; j++) // j is the end index
                {
                    if (surplusCharacter.Contains(s[j]))
                    {
                        var substring = s.Substring(i, j - i);
                        if (substring.Length >= result.Length)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        // we test if substring can be the string that need to be replaced
                        var isValid = true;
                        foreach (var c in surplusCharacter)
                        {
                            if (substring.Count(f => f == c) < counter[c] - div)
                            {
                                isValid = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (isValid)
                            result = substring;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }


}
```

I made some modification to handle borderline cases.
Here is some test sample and the result that I get looks fine
[image]

Comment: (If you're curious, that solution does not pass the tests)

Comment: @user6048670 can you give an example of error? maybe the solution can be improved

Comment: try running it through https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bear-and-steady-gene, the problem I'm ultimately trying to solve

Comment: @AnotherGeek I think your second case can be done with a substring of length 6 instead of 7. You can replace CACCGC with AGAGTT (min length: 6) to give AGAGTTTACCGC.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int balancedString(String s) {
        int[] count = new int[128];
        int n = s.length(), res = n, i = 0, k = n / 4;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            ++count[s.charAt(j)];
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            --count[s.charAt(j)];
            while (i < n && count['A'] <= k && count['C'] <= k && count['T'] <= k && count['G'] <= k) {
                res = Math.min(res, j - i + 1);
                ++count[s.charAt(i++)];
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Adding a comment on what your code does adds a lot of great value to the question~

Answer (score -1):

Thoughts? Sorry for both the messy code + python solution. I initially started writing this on my phone and was feeling lazy.

```
import re
from itertools import permutations

def find_min(s):
    freq = {ch:0 for ch in 'ATGC'}
    for ch in s:
        freq[ch] += 1
    desired_len = int(len(s)/4)
    fixes = {ch:desired_len-freq[ch] for ch in 'ATGC'}
    replacement = ''
    for ch in fixes:
        adj = fixes[ch]
        if adj < 0:
            replacement += ch*(-1*adj)
    perms = set(permutations(replacement))
    m = len(s)
    to_replace = ''
    for rep in perms:
        regex = '.*?'.join([ch for ch in rep])
        finds = re.findall(regex,s)
        if finds:
            x = sorted(finds, key=lambda x:len(x))[0]
            if m >= len(x):
                m = len(x)
                to_replace = x

    print_replacement(s, to_replace, fixes)

def print_replacement(inp, to_replace, fixes):
    replacement = ''
    for ch in to_replace:
        if fixes[ch] > 0:
            replacement += ch
    for ch in fixes:
        if fixes[ch] > 0:
            replacement += ch*fixes[ch]
    print('{0}\t\t- Replace {1} with {2} (min length: {3})'.format(inp ,to_replace, replacement, len(replacement)))


def main():
    inputs =  ["GAAATAAA", "CACCGCTACCGC", "CAGCTAGC", "AAAAAAAA", "GAAAAAAA", "GATGAATAACCA", "ACGT"]
    for inp in inputs:
        find_min(inp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks [@AnotherGeek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38893274/5718020) for the test inputs! Here were the outputs.

```
GAAATAAA        - Replace AAATA with TCCGT (min length: 5)
CACCGCTACCGC    - Replace CACCGC with AGAGTT (min length: 6)
CAGCTAGC        - Replace C with T (min length: 1)
AAAAAAAA        - Replace AAAAAA with CCGGTT (min length: 6)
GAAAAAAA        - Replace AAAAA with CCGTT (min length: 5)
GATGAATAACCA    - Replace ATGAA with TGCGT (min length: 5)
ACGT            - Replace  with  (min length: 0)
```

I realize this is pretty damn inefficient. Any improvement suggestions?